# Append nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

If you have a nested dictionary, where each 'outer' key can map to a dictionary with multiple keys, how do you add a new key to the 'inner' dictionary? For example, I have a list where each element is composed of 3 components: an outer key, an inner key, and a value (A B 10).

Here's the loop I have so far

```
for e in keyList:
    nested_dict[e[0]] = {e[2] : e[3:]}
```

Right now, instead of adding the new key:value to the inner dictionary, any new key:value outright replaces the inner dictionary.

For instance, lets say the keyList is just [(A B 10), (A D 15)]. The result with that loop is

```
{'A' : {'D' : 15}}
```

How can I make it so that instead it's

```
{'A' : {'B' : 10, 'D' : 15}}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You told your code to assign newly created dict to key `e[0]`. It's always replaced blindly and it does not look at previously stored value.

Instead you need something like:

```
for e in keyList:
    if e[0] not in nested_dict:
        nested_dict[e[0]] = {}
    nested_dict[e[0]].update({e[2] : e[3:]})
```

`If` conditional is required to handle 'first key' case. Alternatively `defaultdict` can be used.

```
from collections import defaultdict
nested_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for e in keyList:
    nested_dict[e[0]].update({e[2] : e[3:]})
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the update() function. Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from @ŁukaszRogalski!

Just as an addition, without `defaultdict`, you can use `setdefault`:

```py
keyList = [('A B 10'), ('A D 15')]
nested_dict = {}
for e in keyList:
    rootkey = nested_dict.setdefault(e[0], {})
    rootkey.update({e[2] : e[4:]})

print(nested_dict)  # {'A': {'B': '10', 'D': '15'}}
```